# No puedo instanciar una clase privada en Java

Tags: java-8, class

Estoy siguiendo un código de [github](https://github.com/Avalara/Communications-Developer-Content/blob/master/afc_saaspro_tax/afc_rest_apis/SDK/java/README.md#installation). Mi problema ahora es que hay una linea del código que me dice que es privada y por eso me tira error. Creo que la estoy instanciando bien, pero el error sigue estando.

```
import org.openapitools.client.ApiClient;
import org.openapitools.client.ApiException;
import org.openapitools.client.Configuration;
import org.openapitools.client.api.CustomizationApi;
import org.openapitools.client.model.TaxCalculationSettingTypes;
import org.openapitools.client.model.TaxCalculationSettingsResponse;

class Example {...

        TaxCalculationSettingTypes itemType = new TaxCalculationSettingTypes("Configuration"); 
        try {
            ...
}
```

Y en esta linea: `TaxCalculationSettingTypes itemType = new TaxCalculationSettingTypes("Configuration");` me dice error porque TaxCalculationSettingTypes es privada.

El código de TaxCalculationSettingTypes es el siguiente:

```
@JsonAdapter(TaxCalculationSettingTypes.Adapter.class)
public enum TaxCalculationSettingTypes {
    ALL("All"),
    CONFIGURATION("Configuration"),
    BUNDLE("Bundle"),
    EXCLUSION("Exclusion"),
    OVERRIDE("Override"),
    NEXUS("Nexus"),
    EXEMPTION("Exemption");

    private String value;

    private TaxCalculationSettingTypes(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(this.value);
    }

    public static TaxCalculationSettingTypes fromValue(String value) {
        TaxCalculationSettingTypes[] var1 = values();
        int var2 = var1.length;

        for(int var3 = 0; var3 < var2; ++var3) {
            TaxCalculationSettingTypes b = var1[var3];
            if (b.value.equals(value)) {
                return b;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value '" + value + "'");
    }

    public static class Adapter extends TypeAdapter<TaxCalculationSettingTypes> {
        public Adapter() {
        }

        public void write(JsonWriter jsonWriter, TaxCalculationSettingTypes enumeration) throws IOException {
            jsonWriter.value(enumeration.getValue());
        }

        public TaxCalculationSettingTypes read(JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException {
            String value = jsonReader.nextString();
            return TaxCalculationSettingTypes.fromValue(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Si lo dejo sin parámetros (como esta en github) también tira error, y si le pongo cualquiera de las opciones del enum en String también tira error.

El error que devuelve es el siguiente:

```
error: enum types may not be instantiated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la forma corecta de instanciar una clase `enum` es: `NombreClase nombreObjeto = NombreClase.nombreObjetoEnum;`.
En este caso sería:

```
TaxCalculationSettingTypes itemType = TaxCalculationSettingTypes.CONFIGURATION;
```

Comment: Eso si me anduvo.. gracias!!!